# Screen reader must read dynamic text

Tags: jquery, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda

Hello I have the following html and jquery that replaces text in the text paragraph. I am testing with the nvda screen reader and I want the text in #text to be read aloud when ever I push button one or two. What kind of aria roles / labels  do I need to put on the elements to make that happen?

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
 $('#text').text('This is message one');
});
$('#btn2').click(function(){
 $('#text').text('This is message two');
});
<button id="btn">Read out text</button>
<button id="btn2">Read out text 2</button>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: `I want the text to be read aloud when ever I push button one or two.`=>please explain.

Comment: The nvda screen reader must read the text dynamically inserted in #text whenever #btn or #btn2 is pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more details, you can keep it simple with just `aria-live="polite"`.

```
<button id="btn" aria-live="polite">Read out text</button>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live

If the message is really important, you can use `aria-live="assertive"`.  You can also specify the types of changes you want read (`aria-relevant`) and what parts of the object to be read (`aria-atomic`).  But for now, all you should need is `aria-live="polite"`.